# from and select in c# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [from and select in c# .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322237/from-and-select-in-c-net)

Can anyone please tell me how to specify only particular column in the select statement in the following coding:

```
var combinedrows = from dt1 in DsResults.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                      join dt2 in DsResults.Tables[1].AsEnumerable() on             dt1.Field<string>("MethodName") equals dt2.Field<string>("MethodName")
                      select new { dt1, dt2 };

DataTable finaldt = new DataTable("FinalTable");
finaldt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sp", typeof(string)));
finaldt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Method", typeof(string)));
finaldt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Class", typeof(string)));
finaldt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BLLMethod", typeof(string)));
DataRow newrow = finaldt.NewRow();           
foreach (var row in combinedrows)
{

    DataRow dataRow = finaldt.NewRow();
    dataRow.ItemArray = row.dt1.ItemArray;

     finaldt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
}
```

Comment: You asked this question half an hour ago.

Answer (score 0):

You refine your `select` statemenet:

```
select new { dt1.sp, dt1.Method, dt1.Class }
```

...etc